# What is a good resources to read easy Chinese texts?

Tags: books

I started learning Chinese and want to find some short texts to practice my reading. I've found http://chinesereadingpractice.com/ where you can find some interesting posts, but even beginners text are very complex. 
Is there any resources for very basic and elementary Chinese level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[LingQ](http://www.lingq.com/) has a huge library of texts that generally also include audio. You can read any of the texts you like without paying for a subscription, as long as you don't want to add unknown words to your wordlist (creating LingQs). I have not paid for a subscription and find it to be very useful.

If you do want to create a wordlist of the words you don't know for reviewing in Anki or another SRS program, the I would highly recommend [LWT](http://lwt.sourceforge.net/). I tend to import texts from LingQ so that I can take advantage of the huge library. The system is definitely not as polished as LingQ, but it certainly useful. There are a lot of very useful tutorials for how to use LWT to help with Language learning including:

- [Street Smart Language Learning](http://www.streetsmartlanguagelearning.com/2012/12/using-learning-with-texts-with-anki-2.html);
- [Fluent In 3 Months: Introducing LWT](http://www.fluentin3months.com/learning-with-texts/);
- [The Mezzofanti Guild: How To Install Learning With Texts On Your Own Computer](http://www.mezzoguild.com/2012/07/04/how-to-install-learning-with-texts-lwt).

I have just started on my own reading challenge and this is how I am doing it, but obviously this is just how it works best for me.

Another good place to find reading resources is [Hacking Chinese Resources](http://resources.hackingchinese.com) and Olle's [Reading Chinese Challenge](http://www.hackingchinese.com/extensive-reading-challenge-november-10th-to-30th/) and associated reading resource [post](http://www.hackingchinese.com/the-10-best-free-reading-resource-collections-for-learning-chinese/).

I hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're after short, current affairs reading, also try [Decipher Chinese](http://www.decipherchinese.com). Plenty of articles throughout the week, with some graded as HSK1.  All free.

There is also an app so you can practice reading while on the move with it's dictionary built in, audio etc.